# Check if product variation image is from the variation itself or from the parent

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I want to show the product's variation images. However, if there is no variation image, it just shows the parent's image and I wouldn't expect that. At least I would expect an opportunity to check if the image comes directly from the variation or from the parent.

```
add_action('woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_form', 'test_funktion');
function test_funktion(){
    //Get all variations
    global $product;
    $variationer = $product->get_available_variations();

    //Looping thorugh all
    foreach($variationer as $vari){
        //Get the variation ID
        $varid = $vari['variation_id'];

        //Echoing for testing
        echo '<br>Variation ID: '.$varid.' Image ID: ';

        //Get the image ID from the variation ID
        $variation = new WC_Product_Variation( $varid );
        $image_id = $variation->get_image_id();

        //echoing for testing
        echo $image_id;
    }
}
```

Variation ID 1872 has an image uploaded. The rest does not but they return the parents image ID as shown on the test product: http://webintas.dk/wordpresstest/vare/pike-boots-combat-boot/

How can I check if the returned image is from the parent or from the variation itself?

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

If you check for the image ID with parameter $context = 'edit', you will only get a returned ID if the image is set directly to the variation. The code looks like this:

```
$image_id = $variation->get_image_id('edit');
    if ($image_id){
        //Only if there is an image to the variation itself
        echo $image_id;
    }
```

Ref: https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Product.html#662-671